# 2 Cloud SQL server port forward to cloud proxy vm

Tags: google-cloud-sql, portforwarding, cloud-sql-proxy

I have 2 cloud sql server ( dev and qa) , How to do port forwarding for both sql server to 1 cloud proxy vm.
I did port forwarding for dev sql server long back and its listening on 1433 in cloud proxy vm.

```
sudo iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 1433 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:1433
sudo nohup ./cloud_sql_proxy -instances=project:region:dev-sqlserver=tcp:1433
```

Now i have another qa sql server which i want to do port forwarding in same cloud proxy vm.

I want the way to do port forwarding for both sql server in same cloud proxy vm.

Answer (score 1):

The Cloud SQL Proxy supports multiple instances. As per [documentation](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-proxy?tab=readme-ov-file#basic-usage):

```
./cloud-sql-proxy --port 6000 <INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME_1> <INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME_2>
```

Consider migrating to v2, follow the [Migration Guide](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-proxy/blob/main/migration-guide.md).

Comment: but in case of both db are sql server then how to use their port as sqlserver is running is 1433 only

Comment: Once you start the Proxy, the logs will tell you which IP address and port to use for each SQL Server. Example:


`$ ./cloud-sql-proxy <INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME_1> <INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME_2>`
`Authorizing with Application Default Credentials`
`[INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME_1] Listening on 127.0.0.1:1433`
`[INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME_2] Listening on 127.0.0.1:1434`
`The proxy has started successfully and is ready for new connections!`


You can specify the IP address and port as [per documentation](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-proxy?tab=readme-ov-file#configuring-port)